# Domain of operator which is used in operator monotone function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

We are studying the paper

- Rupert L. Frank, Leander Geisinger, *Refined semiclassical asymptotics for fractional powers of the Laplace operator*, Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik (Crelles Journal), vol. 2016, no. 712 (2016) pp. 1-37, doi:[10.1515/crelle-2013-0120](https://doi.org/10.1515/crelle-2013-0120), [arXiv:1105.5181](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.5181)

and are confused with the proof of Lemma 6.4:

> Lemma 6.4. (Lemma 19 in arXiv preprint) Let $B$ be a non-negative operator with $\operatorname{ker} B=\{0\}$ and let $P$ be an orthogonal projection. Then for any operator monotone function $\phi:(0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
> $$
> P \phi(P B P) P \geq P \phi(B) P .
> $$
> If, in addition, $B$ is positive definite and $\phi$ is not affine linear, then $P \phi(P B P) P=P \phi(B) P$ implies that the range of $P$ is a reducing subspace of $B$.

Here, we recall that for
two operators $A,B$, which are bounded from below, we write $A \leq B$ if their quadratic forms $a, b$ with form domains $\mathcal{D}[a], \mathcal{D}[b]$ satisfy $\mathcal{D}[a] \supset \mathcal{D}[b]$ and $a[u] \leq b[u]$ for every $u \in \mathcal{D}[b]$.

**Problem:** We are confused in the definition of domain of $P\phi(PBP)P$ and $P\phi(B)P$ in the description of Lemma 6.4. The authors seem not to explain why the domain have the containing relationship in their proof.

Thanks for any help.